# Hidden Modal Text Values Not Updating

Tags: razor, modal-dialog

I have an older style modal setup within a helper on a Razor Page like below

```
                    <div id="dl-modal-@a.applicantId" class="modal" style="display: none;">
                        <h3 class="popover-title darkbg">@a.IDTypeDesc Image</h3>
                        <img src="@tblApplicationDocument.GetLicensePictureUrlByApplicantID(a.applicantId)" style="max-width: 500px;"/>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#dl-modal-@a.applicantId" rel="modal:open">@a.IDTypeDesc</a>
```

When the Razor page first gets loaded, i can click the href and everything works fine, but if i close the modal and leave the page and change the value of a, ill come back to the page and the href link has changed to be the correct change, yet when i click the link to open the modal, the h3 text hasnt updated, even though i can see that the value has changed in the watch window. Im confused.

Comment: Did you reload the page after making the data change ? because the C# code gets executed in the server.

Comment: yeah the razor content gets reloaded when you go to a previous page and then back to that page

Comment: So you are not getting the correct value of `IDTypeDesc` property when you render the page ?

Comment: thats the weird part, IDTypeDesc is correct in the watch window, but when the modal opens back up, its the old value

Comment: it must have something to do with the modal not being displayed because the href changes fine when i go between pages